# Xcode: Altering MainStoryboard.storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

Hi I initially created a Single View application in Xcode 4.1 for iPhone. So obviously my storyBoard file was sized accordingly.

Later I changed my settings device's Application target to iPad, but my storyboard file doesn't resize its interface its still sized for the iPhone, how can I change this?

Also how can I orientate the storyboard file to landscape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create new storyboard for iPad from scratch.

Comment: how do i get my view controller scene inside my new story board?

Comment: It's better to recreate it for iPad. May be you would like to use SplitViewController or rearrange controls, you have more space here...